# Transform to anonymous function

Tags: jquery, anonymous-function

I want to convert [this example code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) to a function. I want to do this because I have 2 input fields on the same page which have to make use of this autocomplete. I could do this the old way like I am used to, but I want to learn something about this type of programming. This is what I have now:

```
var Lookup = {
    init: function(field) {
        this.field = field;
        this.autocomplete = null;
        this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById(this.field)), {
            types: ['geocode']
        });
        this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.fillInAddress());
    },
    geolocate: function() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var geolocation = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: geolocation,
                    radius: position.coords.accuracy
                });
                this.autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
            });
        }
    },
    fillInAddress: function() {
        var place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log(place); 
    }
}
```

I execute this with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Lookup.init('location_from');
    Lookup.init('location_to');
});
```

Everything works, the two fields have an autocomplete function. But when I select an address I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

This is happening in the `fillInAddress` function. The AJAX call gets made (request extra details of the place), but then it stops. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to create a jQuery plugin for this task:

```
$.fn.extend({
    geocode: function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this), {
                types: ['geocode']
            });
            ac.addListener('place_changed', function () {
                var place = ac.getPlace();
                console.log(place);
                // ... etc ...
            });
        });
    }
});
```

and

```
$('#location_from, #location_to').geocode();
```